# Get TextView line count in RecyclerView adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to count the number of lines of a `TextView` in a RecyclerView adapter.

Following [answers from other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037377/how-to-get-number-of-lines-of-textview) (although not related to RecyclerViews), I tried adding this to my `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message message = messages.get(position);

    holder.textView.setText(message.getMessage());

    holder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Get the number of lines
    holder.textView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int lineCount = holder.textView.getLineCount();

            Log.d("COUNT", String.valueOf(lineCount));
        }
    });
}
```

But when I open my app, the first RecyclerView item will initially show `COUNT 0` (even though it has 5 lines). But when I scroll down a few items and then scroll back up to the first item, it will show the correct number of lines (`COUNT 5`).

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12107005/4148757

Comment: @bhaskarkurzekar How does that solution affect performance in a RecyclerView?

Answer (score 2):

`textView` is reference to converted view in layout manager. When `run()` is executed, `holder.textView` maybe used in another item.

**UPDATED**

If you fast scroll, some views maybe won't be prepared. You can check that text in current view equals message.

```
Message message = messages.get(position);

holder.textView.setText(message.getMessage());

holder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// Get the number of lines
holder.textView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (holder.textView.getText().toString().equals(message.getMessage()) {
            int lineCount = holder.textView.getLineCount();
            Log.d("COUNT", String.valueOf(lineCount));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Just tried it without the post(Runnable) and it still says `COUNT 0`.

Comment: @user7858218 Do you need to count lines in text or possible number of lines of textView widget?

Comment: The number of lines that appear on screen in the TextView.